# Trouble with overloaded + in complex expressions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I have a class which represents 3D vectors. It has a few member functions(dot product, cross product etc) and also a few overloaded operators (+-*/). I am having trouble using these operators in complex expressions.

In a simplified test case, if I overload the operator as

```
testclass operator+ (testclass& a, testclass& b) {
    return testclass(a.get()+b.get());
}
```

I can do

```
testclass a = testclass(3);
testclass b = testclass(4);
testclass c = a + b;
```

without problems, however a more complicated expression

```
testclass c = a + b + a + b;
```

will fail to compile. I can resolve the issue by changing the overload function to

```
testclass operator+ (testclass a, testclass b) {
    return testclass(a.get()+b.get());
}
```

however, this involves passing by value, which I understand to be slower than the pass by reference scheme in the first case. I am using this class in a piece of math intensive code, and my real class contains three long doubles as data members, so I suspect the performance impact may be substantial.

My questions are:

- Why does this behaviour happen?
- Can I avoid it without resorting to passing by value?
- Will passing by value rather than by reference affect performance anyway, when I have three long doubles as data members? Will an optimising compiler (g++ -O3) optimise it out?

Thanks all in advance.

The exact compile error is:

```
operator_overload.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
operator_overload.cpp:37:29: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘testclass’ and ‘testclass’)
         testclass c = a + b + a + b;
                             ^
operator_overload.cpp:37:29: note: candidate is:
operator_overload.cpp:30:15: note: testclass operator+(testclass&, testclass&)
     testclass operator+ (testclass& a, testclass& b) {
           ^
operator_overload.cpp:30:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘testclass’ to ‘testclass&’
```

My full test code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

class testclass {
public:
    testclass();
    testclass(int);
    int get();
    void set(int);
private:
    int data;
};

testclass::testclass() {
    data = 0;
}

testclass::testclass(int a) {
    data = a;
}

int testclass::get() {
    return data;
}

void testclass::set(int a) {
    data = a;
    return;
}

testclass operator+ (testclass& a, testclass& b) {
    return testclass(a.get()+b.get());
}

int main () {
    testclass a = testclass(3);
    testclass b = testclass(4);
    testclass c = a + b + a + b;
    std::cout << c.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "fail to compile" is not enough, the exact error would be more useful.

Comment: The exact error g++ gives me is:

operator_overload.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
operator_overload.cpp:37:29: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘testclass’ and ‘testclass’)
         testclass c = a + b + a + b;
                             ^
operator_overload.cpp:37:29: note: candidate is:
operator_overload.cpp:30:15: note: testclass operator+(testclass&, testclass&)
     testclass operator+ (testclass& a, testclass& b) {
               ^
operator_overload.cpp:30:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘testclass’ to ‘testclass&’

Comment: did you try `testclass operator+ (const testclass& a, const testclass& b)`

Comment: You made `operator+` return by-value (which is correct) but tempoaries like the values the returned from functions can't bind to non-const lvalue-references. Your parameter should be `const` lvalue-references so they can take rvalues as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that rvalues cannot be bound to lvalue references. The intermediate results in `a + b + a + b`, say `a+b`, are temporaries and the full expression fails to work. OTOH, const references can bind to rvalues. Change the signature to `testclass operator+ (const testclass& a, const testclass& b)` to solve this issue.

For the above signature to make sense, you also need to have `testclass::get` be a `const` method.

Comment: and mark `testclass::get()` as `const` or you won't be able to call it on a `const` reference.

Comment: @Jack, thanks! Will add that. Assumed that a method named get would be `const` :)

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to use const qualifiers to hold refs to rvalue

you code:

```
#include <iostream>

class testclass {
public:
    testclass();
    testclass(int);
    int get() const;
    void set(int);
private:
    int data;
};

testclass::testclass() {
    data = 0;
}

testclass::testclass(int a) {
    data = a;
}

int testclass::get() const {
    return data;
}

void testclass::set(int a){
    data = a;
    return;
}

testclass operator+ (const testclass& a, const testclass& b) {
    return testclass(a.get()+b.get());
}

int main () {
    testclass a = testclass(3);
    testclass b = testclass(4);
    testclass c = a + b + a + b;
    std::cout << c.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

works for me, gcc 4.9.2

Comment: What is a `refs`
? :D

Comment: Thanks, made all of the things const in my real code and it fixed the issue :)

nbro, a ref is short for reference, they're pretty much a way of passing variables to functions without having to copy them every time - you pass a reference to the initial copy rather than creating an identical copy to use in the function when you call the function. That's an oversimplification, but a proper explanation won't fit in this box, and there are better people to get that from than me :P